# Convert Date: Day Mon YYYY hh:mm AM CET

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have these dates, that I need converted to date:

Sat Nov 22 2014 01:01 AM CET

Mon Aug 18 2014 06:32 PM CEST

All the convert or cast functions I tried didn't work, maybe someone has an idea what to do?

In the end, I would need something like
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS that doesn't really matter, but I would need them in the same timezone if at all possible...

Thank You for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server can convert that if you get rid of the day of the week at the beginning and the time zone at the end:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('Sat Nov 22 2014 01:01 AM CET',4,LEN('Sat Nov 22 2014 01:01 AM CET')-7))
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('Mon Aug 18 2014 06:32 PM CEST',4,LEN('Mon Aug 18 2014 06:32 PM CEST')-7))
```

I'm not sure what you mean that you need them in the same time zone.

Comment: if I try that, I get: "[2014-12-02 22:34:03] [S0001][241] Fehler beim Konvertieren einer Zeichenfolge in ein Datum und/oder eine Uhrzeit." I don't know the exact english version of the error, but it says, there has been an error while converting a string into a date and / or a time.

Comment: with the same timezone, I mean that ideally, it would convert both to UTC or the server timezone, or some other 'same' timezone

Comment: You must have a different collation that me - when I run that I get the correct dates.  You should still be able to reproduce what I did - trim off the day name and timezone and convert that.  If you need to adjust the hour based on the time zone you'll need additional (and rather complex) logic.

Comment: If I try it with the string, it works just fine, you're right. Only if I actually run it against the database it fails. I don't know why, I copied the string directly out of the SELECT * output. Thank you anyway, I think this is the correct solution and I just have some mistake somewhere

Comment: It's likely you have some data with shorter or longer day or time zone names.

Comment: somehow this one is a trouble: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Mar 17 2014 06:38 PM') any idea why?

Comment: That one doesn't have the day name in front and the time zone at the end.

Comment: I stripped those already. The above command is the part that fails, even as a string, executed like this. SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Apr 17 2014 06:38 PM') works like expected, with Mar it doesn't

Comment: For me it worked with Mar - SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Mar 17 2014 06:38 PM') returns 2014-03-17 18:38:00.000

Comment: it was expecting "Mär", apparently it was set to German. SET LANGUAGE us_english; did the trick. thank you very much